# is there an elegant way to add key/value to an object from an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

As part of a angular2/typescript project I have an array of objects. The objects contain a set of key/value pairs that come from a database. That then gets mapped to a table on the ui side (using `ag-grid-ng2`).

The headers for the table are dynamic and set in the DB.

one task I have is to map an array of key/values to a single object, like this:

```
const things = [
  {
    field: 'some_table_header', 
    humanReadable: 'Some table header'
  }
];
```

turns into:

```
const anObjectFullOfThings = {
  some_table_header: 'Some table header'
};
```

I currently feel my code could be much more elegant and concise, i.e.:

```
let anObjectFullOfThings = {};

things.forEach((thing) => {
  anObjectFullOfThings[thing.field] = thing.humanReadable;
});
```

I feel there must be something better, i.e. to go the other way i'd map over Object.keys etc. Is there an alternative way to map an array to object keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is just fine.

Some people would use `reduce`:

```
let anObjectFullOfThings = things.reduce((obj, thing) => {
    obj[thing.field] = thing.humanReadable;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

...but it's a matter of taste, particularly as the `reduce` isn't really reducing anything, it's just perpetuating the same object throughout the loop.

Comment: get your point about taste. it actually fits really well with the rest of the implementation. Thanks